# Linux Mint. Проблема с установкой драйвера Nvidia.

Tags: ubuntu

Здравствуйте. Я давно сталкивался с такой проблемой - на моем мониторе (16:9) не возможно сидеть с разрешением 1024x786. Проблема в том, что он все растягивает и в итоге все огромное (окно на весь экран). А в настройках не могу поменять разрешение, т.к. нет соотвуствующих драйверов. Я залез на офф. сайт NVIDIA и скачал оттуда драйвера для видео карты NVIDIA GTS 250. Дальше поискал в яндексе информацию об установке драйверов в Linux и решил установить вот по [этой инструкции](http://linux-bsd.in.ua/asplinux/161-ustanovka-drajverov-dlya-videokart-nvidia-v-ubuntu.html)

Но при запуске этой команды

```
sudo sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86-290.10.run
```

в терминале открылась программа, которая вывела ошибку:
ERROR: Your appear to be running an X server;
В обще суть ошибки в том, что надо выйти из X Server. Я нажал ctrl-alt-f1, вышла консоль, я ввел логин и пароль. прописал опять строку для установки драйвера но вышла та же ошибка. 
В чем может быть проблема? Как её исправить. Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не факт что другой ранлевел поможет, иксы могут и на третьем вертеться, на первом их точно нет, но там может еще каких-других служб не хватать.

Когда перейдете в терминал по ф1 введите

```
/etc/init.d/gdm stop
```

для Gnome, или kdm для kde, или lightdm для unity.

ЗЫ. Когда я последний раз ставил дрова из репа вышло вот что, Debian Wheezy, NVidia

[image: снимок]

Answer (score 1):

Так надо остановить иксы вообще. Перейдя на первый текстовый терминал вы иксы не остановили. Это может зависеть от дистрибутива, но обычно достаточно остановить какую-нибудь службу, обеспечивающую работу иксов (в мандриве, например, /etc/init.d/dm stop) или перейти на другой ранлевел (что-то типа init 3)

Comment: сам недавно ставил. init 3 в рутовой консоле вводит линукс в правильное состояние. Потом можно смело запускать NVIDIA-Linux-x86-290.10.run.
P.S. проверял на debian 5.0.5 и Fedora 15|16.

Comment: В убунтах init 3 не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Я на убунту под GTX285 так ставлю дрова.

Сначала нужно установить (если не установлен) пакет build-essential:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Далее указанным способом (Ctr-Alt-F{1-6}) переходим в консоль.

Отключаем иксы. Для этого останавливаем диспетчер дисплея. GNOME использует gdm (во всяком случае так делал GNOME2). KDE использует kdm, а Xfce - lightdm.

sudo /etc/init.d/gdm stop

Далее наша задача - отключить загрузку видеодрайвера nouveau. Раньше это надо было делать вручную. Теперь драйвер NVIDIA  сам может добавить в конфиги нужную информацию.

Запускаем установку драйвера

```
sudo sh NVIDIA-Linux-....
```

В определенный момент он выдаст сообщение об ошибке по-английски примерно такого содержания: "типа, на вашей системе запущен драйвер nouveau, но я могу его отключить, сделать где-то там нужные записи." Мы соглашаемся. Он заканчивает свою работу с сообщением об ошибке. Перегружаемся

```
sudo reboot
```

Если nouveau отключился, то иксы запустятся с ужасным видом: огромные значки и т.д. Мы говорим промежуточное ура и переходим опять в консоль. Там так же отключаем иксы и запускаем установку драйвера. Он предлагает установить свои библиотеки OpenGL, соглашаемся, предлагает в конце что-то куда-то записать, отказываемся. Если говорит, что все нормально установилось, то либо перегружаемся, либо запускаем иксы

```
cd
startx
```

Если что-то пойдет не так, пиши, будем разбираться.

P.S. Лучше ставь рекомендованный драйвер 275.36, у меня с 290 какой-то баг вылез.